# Why did plants evolve to use opioids?

Tags: botany, organic-chemistry

I'm reading about medicine and specifically opioids. There seems to be a wide variety of forms of these chemicals, I'm curious as to what purpose these serve in these respective plants, and why they function the way they do in mammals.

Comment: Please tell us what you found in your reading. :)

Comment: Welcome to Bio and thank you for this interesting questions. I must say this question is too broad imo. A way to narrow it down, for a starters, is split this question up in two separate questions. One on plants, one on brains. Does that make any sense?